# Vectorizing raster with values between 0 and 1 in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, vectorization

I am working on QGIS. I have a raster of EVI, in which values are comprised between `0` and `1`. I need to vectorize this raster in order to make an intersection with another vector.

My issue is that when I vectorize my raster, the values are either `0` or `1`, but I want the values detailed between 0 and 1. The best would be to have the values every `0.1` (`0.1, 0.2, 0.3, ...`).
Do you have any idea of how I can proceed?

I was thinking that I could multiply the values of the raster by a hundred, but is that even possible?

Answer (score 4):

Use the ["Raster pixels to polygons" tool](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#raster-pixels-to-polygons).  It will convert the floating point values correctly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Command line is the easiest, with GDAL tools.

1. Convert the raster to XYZ data:

   ```
   gdal_translate -of XYZ input.tif input.csv
   ```
2. Use an editor to filter out any **nodata** values in the CSV file if you prefer
3. Filter out a range of pixels according to the value of the raster (Z-value) if required.
4. Load the XYZ data as a delimited text file in QGIS.

You can now use the layer to intersect with other vectors.

#### Grid

[image: Grid]

#### Points

[image: Points]

#### Filtered and Styled Points

[image: Filtered and Styled Points]